# iperf3 seems to be stuck after initial connection

Tags: iperf

Yesterday, my tests with iperf3 were working fine.
Today unfortunately it seems the initial connection is made but it freezes after that.

Below the outputs.

### Server:

```
Server listening on TCP port 5201
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 185.70.XXX.XXX port 5201 connected with 85.73.XXX.XXX port 55217
```

### Client:

```
D:\Tools\iperf3>iperf3 -c 185.70.XXX.XXX -p 5201
```